# How to use normal output with systemctl instead of less/more?

Tags: linux, systemctl, pager

For example: `systemctl list-units --type service` by default uses redirection to less/more, how to disable it?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/356753/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/474514/117549 and a probable duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/343168/117549

Comment: Dmitry, you'll want to register and use *this* account, so that you can edit your post as needed, along with accepting answer(s) that solve your problem.